# Static value inside a colum of a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

Hello Is there anyway to put a static value in my database

Example I will input just the name Dave in my textbox   Name `____Dave.mp3______`

then output in the column inside the database is "sound\Dave.mp3"
I want to put a Static value inside the column of AuditoPath Column
Is this possible? how to do it?

The static value is "sound\";

Thank you Sorry for the Bad english

The column Audiopath only

Thanks in advance.

```
$query = "insert into question values(" . $_SESSION['testqn'] . 
",$newstd,'" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['question'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','". 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionb'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionc'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiond'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['marks'],ENT_QUOTES) . "','". 
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['AudioPath'],ENT_QUOTES) ."')";
```

Comment: I think instead of inserting a single static value in a database table use php constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
Before insert query you need to do this
$path="sound\"; //path
$name="Dave.mp3"; //name

$insername=$path.$name; concate path and name ( Use insert to this variable)
```

Comment: if its ok can you show me? I am little Confuse on how will i Connect $name  to my textbox

Comment: echo $insername .its display you answer